# Finding the length of a side of a shape using differentiation

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

I have been presented with the following question:

An open metal tank with a square base is made from $12 m^2$ of sheet metal. Find
the length of the side of the base for the volume of the tank to be a maximum
and find this maximum volume.

I have no idea how to answer this question, any help with the methodology showing how to get to the answer would be very much appreciated.

this is the original question:
[image]

Comment: 12 m^2 here is supposed to mean 12 sq. metres, right?

Comment: yes thats what it means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the side of the square base be x m.

Then area of the square base is $x^2 m^2$

Area of metal sheet $12 m^2$

So out of $12 m^2$ we have $x^2$ used for base.

Then remaining area is used for 4 walls of container is $(12 −x^2) m^2$

This would be divided in the four sides/walls of the container with side x.

So we have $\frac{(12 −x^2) m^2}{4x m}$ as a height.

The volume of the container would be length * breadth * height.

V = $ x m * x m * \frac{(12 −x^2) m}{4x}$

= $\frac{(12x −x^3) m^3}{4}$

Now differentiate w.r.t x,

$\frac{d}{dx}V(x) = V′(x) = \frac{12 - 3x^2}{4} $

= $ 3 − \frac{3 x^2}{4}$

We equate it to 0 and get $x = \pm 2$

But x=2 becasue it can’t be −2 here.

Also,

$V′′(x) = \frac{−3x}{2} < 0$

So maximum volume.

Length of side x = 2 m, V(x) = $4 m^3$, height = 1 m.